# Cardinal of power of maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, local-rings

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ such that
$$|A/m|=p^f$$
with $p$ prime integer.
I have to prove that if $A/m^r$ is finite then
$$|(A/m^r)^*|=p^{r-1}(p^f-1).$$
Could anyone give me some advice ?